# Как преобразовать текстовый файл в json?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, поиск-библиотек

Посоветуйте хороший npm-пакет для преобразования текстов в json-файл. Или если в ручную прописать, то как лучше всего?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const fs = require('fs')
const getFiles = () => fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files');

console.log(getFiles())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const result = getFiles().map(file => {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + file, {encoding: 'utf8'})
    return {
      file,
      content
    }
  })
  res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) не пойдёт?

Comment: @AlexSazonov уже рассматриваю как вариант, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Функция `JSON.Parse` переводит строку в объект.

```
var str = '{a:123,b:"string"}'

var obj = JSON.Parse(str)
console.log(obj.a) // 123
console.log(obj.b) // "string"
```